# How to get real time stock price and plot chart

Tags: python, reactjs, django, google-play, stock

I'm working on a project in which I have to get the stock price in real time and plot the chart (like tradingview, yahoo etc) in react js.

I have found a few APIs on RapidAPI but they allow to limited API call per minute.

Tech stack: python, django for back-end and react js for front-end

Comment: There is no question. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Check this function :

```
import urllib.request 
import json 
 
class GoogleFinanceAPI: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.prefix = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" 
     
    def get(self,symbol,exchange): 
        url = self.prefix+"%s:%s"%(exchange,symbol) 
        u = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
        content = u.read().decode('utf-8') 
        obj = json.loads(content[3:]) 
        return obj[0] 
         
         
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    c = GoogleFinanceAPI() 
    quote = c.get("RELIANCE","NSE") 
    print(quote)
```